# How to execute shell scripts on the backend of a nodejs web app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, backend, mern

I have a full stack MERN application running on a google compute engine, along with a local mongodb running on the same server. Its a CRUD application, however, I have a script that is stored in the server that I would like triggered everytime a user presses a button on the front end. (a use case would be, user enters some input that is logged into the database, and when its logged I would like a script triggered on the backend that creates a json file out of the mongodb table and uploads it to github/emails it out).

I'm not sure where to start learning this, a few google searches have led me to AJAX and child_processes, am I going in the right direction? Any resources or pointers would be great. Thank you

Comment: Not sure if you are looking for a 'shell script'. More like using Node's File System library to create/edit files on the folder.

Comment: I guess more specifically I would like user input/button press to execute command line arguments on the server back end if that is possible?

Comment: Yeah definitely, use something like Axios to hit an endpoint that will run a 'controller' function that will do what you need to do. Very basic MVC stuff here it looks like

Comment: could you check my understanding? What your saying is I should create a new endpoint on my backend where I type whatever endpoint arguments I want to use...... then say if the command line argument needs arguments from user input, then I could use a axios post request and execute the command line argument with user input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly then you want to accomplish the following things:

```
1. Export json data from a local MongoD instance.
2. Then send that data to github or email it somewhere.
```

In that case I would recommend to use `child process(exec, spawn, execFile, fork)` to execute the `mongoexport` command to get `.json` files.

But I don't recommend using shell script to upload that data to github or email it.

Use the `github api` for github and use `node-mailer` to email the data.

To learn more about `child processes` read the docs here [Node.js v14.x Child process docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/child_process.html)

Comment: So just to clarify, when a user presses a button, I can add a child process that calls mongoexport and git CLIs to get what I need done?

Comment: Well, I think if I were doing it I would create an endpoint or route `api/getdata` or whatever with authentication. Then when you click the button in the frontend and your app would send a request to that endpoint. Let's say that endpoint is handled by a file named `getData.js`. So `getData.js` would create a child process to execute the `mongoexport` command to get all the files and upload it using `github api` not with `git cli` (just like how u use fetch to send data).  Learn about github api here: [Github Rest Api](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-rest-api).

Comment: By the way in nodejs we don't have native `fetch api`. We use `http` module instead. But there is a library called `node-fetch` if you want to use fetch api in nodejs.

Comment: Thank you, would it matter which type of http request I send if I just want to run some command line arguments? for example, everytime the user presses a certain button I just the server to run mongoexport, does it matter if it was triggered by a get or post request? I assume I would need to use a post request if i wanted user input to be incorporated in the command line argument

Comment: If your request has to carry some data then certainly a post request. By the way, be careful when taking `cli arguments` from user. It would be a major vulnerability to take command line arguments from non admin users. For example let's say you're running the `git log` command and a user passes `--oneline && echo you_r_in_danger`, guess what the 2nd cmd would also be executed. That way I can easily hack your whole server. So watch out and do validation. At last if my answer solves your problem then marking the answer as accepted and a up vote would be really appreciated <3 .